# Why I couldn't detect other Bluetooth devices using CoreBluetooh in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I created a simple app that trying to detech bluetooth devices around my iPhone. I followed this tutorial: [BLE Development for iOS](https://www.novelbits.io/intro-ble-mobile-development-ios-part-2/)

Here's my code:

The View:

```
struct BluetoothDevicesView: View {
@ObservedObject var bleManager = BLEManager()

var body: some View {
    VStack (spacing: 10) {
        Text("Bluetooth Devices")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        
        List(bleManager.peripherals) { peripheral in
            HStack {
                Text(peripheral.name)
                Spacer()
                Text(String(peripheral.rssi))
            }
        }
        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Text("STATUS")
            .font(.headline)
        
        // Status goes here
        if bleManager.isSwitchedOn {
            Text("Bluetooth is switched on")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        else {
            Text("Bluetooth is NOT switched on")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        
        Spacer()
        VStack (spacing: 25) {
            Button(action: {
                bleManager.startScanning()
            }) {
                Text("Start Scanning")
            }
            Button(action: {
                bleManager.stopScanning()
            }) {
                Text("Stop Scanning")
            }
        }.padding()
        Spacer()
    }
}
}
```

Next is the `BLEManager.swift`

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

struct Peripheral: Identifiable {
let id: Int
let name: String
let rssi: Int
}

class BLEManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

var myCentral: CBCentralManager!
@Published var isSwitchedOn = false
@Published var peripherals = [Peripheral]()

override init() {
    super.init()
    
    myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    myCentral.delegate = self
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        isSwitchedOn = true
    }
    else {
        isSwitchedOn = false
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let newPeripheral = Peripheral(id: peripherals.count, name: peripheral.name ?? "Unknown", rssi: RSSI.intValue)
    print(newPeripheral)
    peripherals.append(newPeripheral)
print("peripheral: \(peripheral)")
}


func startScanning() {
    print("startScanning")
    myCentral.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
}

func stopScanning() {
    print("stopScanning")
    myCentral.stopScan()
}
```

}

Inside `didDiscover peripheral`, I changed the source code to current since it results the same. Now, when I run it shows something like this:

[image]

Around my device, there are iPad, Mac, K1 device (some kind of android) but where are they? In bluetooth settings they can be detected but through this app I can't.

Can someone explain why I can't detect them? Out of 10 bluetooth detected, why only 2 of them detected? And why the others detected as `nul` or `Unknown` in my case? Did I miss anything?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

UPDATE:

I print `print("peripheral: \(peripheral)")`, the outcome is like so. So many (`null') that I wish they are names.

[image]

Comment: You are detecting the devices, you just aren't getting their name. The advertisement doesn't always contain the device name. If you actually connect to the device you will typically see the device name.

Comment: Paulw is correct. Try printing the advertisementData for each peripheral — that may include a name or other useful information.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answering. Printing `advertisementData` will give me a bunch of words and numbers that i couldn't read or explain to you, but printing `peripheral` doesn't always give me the device name. While bluetooth on settings can detect their name even android devices or laptop that I want to detect. Why I can't detect their name? it always `(null)`. I do not want to connect them, just detect them for now. Any suggestion? Please check screenshots update. @Paulw11 @Adam

Comment: Also if I may ask, is there anything to do with `BLE` and `classic bluetooth`? Is there any limitation that BLE can't detect a classic bluetooth? and does core bluetooth contain both BLE and classic bluetooth? @Paulw11

Comment: iOS apps only have visibility of BLE devices through Core Bluetooth.  In general apps cannot discover or work with classic Bluetooth devices; The exception being MFi Bluetooth devices that are registered against your specific app.

Answer (score 1):

The scan will only detect devices that are advertising. Think of it as a device that is screaming "I'm here!". If a device is connected to your phone, it doesn't need to advertise its location, so it won't appear on your scan.

That what the "pairing mode" of some devices do, it starts the advertisement to let others devices know it's there.

You can download other popular scanners, like nRF for Android to confirm it's seeing the same devices as the app you are developing.